# PHP pagination does not change the values on page

Tags: php, pagination

I have used the php pagination tutorial: http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/29.html. And as it said it was easy I did not expect any problems. However, I have encountered one. Now I know for the best results you should see my source code so I shall provide it. The problem is that it queries fine and only displays certain data on the page if the member is right and limits it to only a few per page... However it does not change values when I try to change to see more comments on the next page.

```
        <?php
        /*  $dbLink = mysql_connect("localhost", "sco0100_james", "creeper");
            mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8", $dbLink);
            mb_language('uni');
            mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
        */

        include('config.php');  // include your code to connect to DB.

        $tbl_name="commenttable";  //your table name
        $adjacents = 3;        

    /* 
    First get total number of rows in data table. 
    If you have a WHERE clause in your query, make sure you mirror it here.
    */

        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name";
        $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
        $total_pages = $total_pages[num];

        /* Setup vars for query. */
        $targetpage = "profile.php?id=$id"; //the name of this file
        $limit = 3;             //how many items to show per page
        $page = $_GET['page'];

        if($page) 
            $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;  
                           //first item to display on this page
        else
            $start = 0;    //if no page var is given, set start to 0

        /* Get data. */
        $sql = "SELECT id, name, comment, member1, member2 FROM $tbl_name WHERE member2='".$id."' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $start, $limit";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        /* Setup page vars for display. */
        if ($page == 0) 
            $page = 1;  //if no page var is given, default to 1.

        $prev = $page - 1;  //previous page is page - 1
        $next = $page + 1;  //next page is page + 1
        $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      
                    //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
        $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;  //last page minus 1

    /* 
        Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
        We're actually saving the code to a variable in case 
                    we want to draw it more than once.
    */

        $pagination = "";

        if($lastpage > 1)
        {   
            $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";

            //previous button
            if ($page > 1) 
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\">previous</a>";
            else
                $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">� previous</span>"; 

            //pages 
            if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   
                            //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
            {   
                for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
            }

            elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    
                             //enough pages to hide some
            {
                //close to beginning; only hide later pages
                if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
                {
                    for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                    }

                    $pagination.= "...";
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
                }

                //in middle; hide some front and some back
                elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
                {
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
                    $pagination.= "...";

                    for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                    }

                    $pagination.= "...";
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
                }

                //close to end; only hide early pages
                else
                {
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
                    $pagination.= "...";

                    for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                        else    
                            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                    }
                }
            }

    //next button
    if ($page < $counter - 1) 
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">next</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next</span>";
        $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
}

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $cname= $row['name'];
        $comment= $row['comment'];
        echo $cname . '<br/>' . '<br/>' . $comment . '<br/>' . '<br/>' . '<hr size="1"/>';
    }
?>

    <?=$pagination?>
```

I suspect the problem could be my $targetpage which opens different data for the profile depending on which id it has for each different user. But I do not know how to correct this, or if this is even the problem... can anyone see whats wrong? (FIXED)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `$targetpage` is incorrect:

```
 $targetpage = "profile.php?id=$id";
```

will produce something like `profile.php?id=42`. You then use that string in your urls:

```
 <a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter etc..." />
```

which gives you the actual generated HTML:

```
 <a href="profile.php?id=42?page=XXX" />
```

This is incorrect. a query string should have only a SINGLE `?`. You need to use `&` for subsequent parameters, e.g.:

```
 <a href=\"$targetpage&page=$counter etc..." />
                      ^--- &, not ?
```

Comment: Arigato. That has worked ^.^ Well... as far as I see now it has worked. I will post back if I find later it did something wrong

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query should contain a TOP and a LIMIT value, so they you select the range (page) that you intended.  Something similar to this:

```
$items_per_page = 10;
$query = "SELECT TOP $items_per_page * FROM table LIMIT ". $items_per_page * $REQUEST['page'];
```

Comment: $limit is the items per page variable in my code. And that is shown in the $sql query. But I shall change abit of that now and see what happens, thanks.

Comment: That produces an error later in the code where it is called. The error is: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource. And this is the code I changed it to:    $sql = "SELECT TOP $limit * FROM $tbl_name WHERE member2='".$id."' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT ". $limit * $REQUEST['page'];